# How switch statement in FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem() work?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Have a look at this code :

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index){

       Log.i("Tab position", String.valueOf(index));
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }    

       @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 3;
        }
```

`ViewPager` works fine but how ?

1. When i start my app i get following Logcat with TabPosition 0 and 1:

   `09-16 15:28:20.353: I/Tab position(2737): 0
    09-16 15:28:20.372: I/Tab position(2737): 1`
2. Now when i select second Tab or swipe to second page i get following Logcat with TabPosition 2:

   `09-16 15:28:29.072: I/Tab position(2737): 2`
3. when i select third Tab or swipe to third page then there is no Logcat and TabPosition not printed :

My confusion is I know that index returned by `getItem()` is not a position of current selected Page or Tab but it is a position of pages that need to be rendered.

But if this is a case then how switch statement returns correct Fragment although index is not correct one.

For example :

**Initially there are two indexes returned by `getItem()` 0 and 1, now how switch statement decides to select 0 or 1.**

I hope you understand question.

Comment: What does getCount of your adapter return?  It should be 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this:

When you set the adapter the ViewPager will ask the adapter for the first fragment to display (index 0) and for the one to the right (index 1).

That is because the ViewPager always caches some pages besides the one that's currently shown. The default value for "some" is 1 but you can change it with

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Note that 0 has no left neighbor (index -1), so only indices 0 and 1 are loaded at the beginning.

Now, when you page to index 1, the ViewPager already has the corresponding fragment in its cache and can display it right away. But it will also ask the adapter for index 2, because it will be the next one.

Similarly, when you page to index 2, it already has the fragment and can display it. And since 2 has no right neighbor (which the ViewPager knows from your getCount) there is nothing more to load...

Edit: So, to answer your original question more directly: The switch statement never has to decide between 0 and 1. getItem is called once for 0 and  once for 1, it returns the appropriate fragment in each case and then the ViewPager decides which of these to display.

Comment: Thanx.I know this, my doubt is how switch statement will decide to select 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Just edited my answer to address this more directly.

Comment: But if `getItem()` is giving 1 then switch statement should select 1st fragment.Which is not happening here.

Comment: Of course it does! But getView(1) is not called when you swipe to/select the second Fragment (index 1) - instead, the Fragment is pre-loaded by the ViewPager when the first Fragment (index 0) is still displayed. Try setting setOffScreenPageLimit(0) on your ViewPager - then the ViewPager will never cache any Fragments and will always call getItem(x) when you navigate to the xth page. OTOH try setOffScreenPageLimit(2) and you will see that the ViewPager creates all Fragments when the first one is shown and will then never again call getItem because it has all Fragments cached.