# FragmentPagerAdapter is not returning exact position at Fragment getItem(int index)

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image][image]###Hi All.
I have implemented Tab with swipe effect .But the problem is when i am clicking on Tab to get current position, Clicking is happening on 2 positions . When i am printing the position its showing position: 0
and 1. i have tried and i googled also.I have posted my Images.

### The "All Categories" Tab having another Fragment Not Games Screen .The position of Games Fragment is 1 but not 0. But 0 positions its showing

#### Help me out anyone?Same question like [How switch statement in FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866759/how-switch-statement-in-fragmentpageradapters-getitem-work)

My code is:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println(index);
        return new ArticlesList();
    case 1:
        System.out.println(index);
        // Games fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    case 2:
        System.out.println(index);
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 3:
        System.out.println(index);
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 4:
        System.out.println(index);
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 5:
        System.out.println(index);
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    case 6:
        System.out.println(index);
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 7;
}
```

}

Comment: post the image of the tab view you are getting on phone

Comment: I have added Image and description also

Comment: Please explain what you want to do and expect from the behaviour in a clear and easy to understand way. The getItem() method of the adapter has nothing to do with clicking and providing the right index of when clicking on tabs. Use 'int index = pager.getCurrentItem(); pagerAdapter.getFragment(index);' for that

Answer (score 2):

It works like this:

When you set the adapter the ViewPager will ask the adapter for the first fragment to display (index 0) and for the one to the right (index 1).

That is because the ViewPager always caches some pages besides the one that's currently shown. The default value for "some" is 1 but you can change it with

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Note that 0 has no left neighbor (index -1), so only indices 0 and 1 are loaded at the beginning.

Now, when you page to index 1, the ViewPager already has the corresponding fragment in its cache and can display it right away. But it will also ask the adapter for index 2, because it will be the next one.

Similarly, when you page to index 2, it already has the fragment and can display it. And since 2 has no right neighbor (which the ViewPager knows from your getCount) there is nothing more to load...

Try setting setOffScreenPageLimit(0) on your ViewPager - then the ViewPager will never cache any Fragments and will always call getItem(x) when you navigate to the xth page.

Thanks david.mihola: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25867199/4176045

Comment: I solved my self, by applying (position-1), thanks +1 for same thought

Answer (score 1):

what its doing is, it is initalizing two fragment a time... the fragment which you can see and the next fragment... if u print a long onCreate of fragment you will get clear idea

Comment: sorry.. can you please explain me more

Comment: just print logs on life cycle methods on the Fragments and observe the logs... you will get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

```
 FragmentManager fragmntMgr;
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmntMgr
            .beginTransaction();

    // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.rightsidein,0);

    List<Fragment> list = fragmntMgr.getFragments();

    if (list != null) {
        for (Fragment element : list) {

            if (element != null) {
                ft.remove(element);
                fragmntMgr.popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have posted i am not getting.Could you please explain me